# How can I handle exceptions raised by webservice methods in SudzC in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services

I'm working with WebServices, and I'm using SudzC lib in my iOS applicaition. Some of methods in WSDL throw exceptions. How can I handle them?

Comment: have you tried using delegate methods, onfault and onerror

Comment: Some exception types are defined in wsdl. And SudzC generate obj-c classes for this exception types. But I can't get this generated exception classes in onfault and onerror